# Concepts of parameters and services

Tags: ros, services, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going through this tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams) and am unclear about one thing. After setting a new parameter (rosparam set background_r 150), why we need to call clear service (rosservice call clear) to make the change take effect?

How do they work? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10109/concepts-of-parameters-and-services/) by [roboren](https://answers.ros.org/users/609/roboren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2011-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The parameter is only stored in the parameter server (that lives with roscore). When you change it the program does not necessarily know about this and will not react to a change.

The clear service call just triggers the program to redraw and in the process acquire the current (newly set) parameter.

For parameter changes that should take effect immediately there is [dynamic_reconfigure](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5